# maximum modulus principle with zeros at origin

Tags: complex-analysis

Just to make sure the following argument is correct:

Suppose $f: \Delta(0,1) \to \mathbb{C}$ is bounded (by a constant $M$), holomorphic. Say we have $f(z) = z^kg(z)$, where $g(z)$ is still holomorphic but $g(0) \neq 0$.

Then we split the open disk into two parts $|z| \leq r$ and $r < |z| < 1$. Then maximum modulus principle on the first area gives $g(z) \leq M/r^k$. For the second area we have $|z^k| > r^k$ and therefore $|g(z)| < M/r^k$. Now push $r \to 1$, we have $|g(z)| \leq M$.

If we have $f$ continuous on the unit circle we can just use MMP there, but since we never assume it in the argument above, am I getting something out of nothing?

Comment: what is $g$ ? can you be more clear please

Comment: @Hamza Oops...corrected

Comment: The bound on the second are is not correct (since you'd also have to control the modulus of $g$ on the circle $|z|=1$). However, it's not needed, since you already know that $|g(z)|\leq Mr^{-k}$ for $|z|\leq r$ by the MMP. Now let $r\to 1^-$ to conclude.

Comment: Wait...why do I have to control modulus of $g$ on circle $|z|=1$? Is there something wrong with $|z^k| = |z|^k > r^k$ implying $|g| = |f/z^k| < M/r^k$?